# Como fazer um insert em cascata em varias tabelas de uma vez, quando um der certo faz o outro?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela com o nome de questionário, perguntas e respostas.
Eu preciso fazer um insert na tabela questionario, logo em seguida receber o id da tabela questionario, para quando for inserir as perguntas eu inserir com o id do questionario, e a mesma coisa com as resposta.
Quando eu for inserir as respostas insere com o id da pergunta.
Ou seja insere NA TABELA QUESTIONARIO, DEPOIS NA TABELA PERGUNTAS E DEPOIS NA TABELA RESPOSTA.
Queria inserir tudo de uma só vez.
Estou usando php, e mysql.

Codigo do banco.

```
public function novoquestionario($nome_questionario, $descricao, $categoria, $autor){
    try{$stmt = "
        INSERT INTO
        questionario (myid, nome_questionario, descricao, categoria, data, data_update,  autor)
        VALUES (NULL, :nome_questionario, :descricao, :categoria, :data, :data2, :autor)";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($stmt);
        $stmt->bindValue(":nome_questionario", $nome_questionario);
        $stmt->bindValue(":descricao", $descricao);
        $stmt->bindValue(":categoria", $categoria);
        $stmt->bindValue(":data", date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $stmt->bindValue(":data2", date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $stmt->bindValue(":autor", $autor);    
        $stmt->execute();
        return $this->processResults($stmt); 
    }
    catch (Exception $e){  
        $log = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($log, "ERRO EM 'pesRastreioDAO -> instPesRast' -=- DIA ".date("d/m/Y")." -=- HORA ".date("H:m:s")."\r\n".$e->getMessage()."\r\n");
        fclose($log);
        return false;
    }
}


private function processResults($stmt){
    $results = array();
    if($stmt) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

            $objt = new Questionario();

            if (isset($row->myid)){
                $objt->setMyid($row->myid);
            }else{
                $objt->setMyid(NULL);
            }  
            if (isset( $row->nome_questionario)){
                $objt->setNome_questionario($row->nome_questionario);
            }else  {
                $objt->setnome_questionario(NULL);  
            }
            if (isset($row->descricao)){  
                $objt->setDescricao($row->descricao);
            }
            else{
                $objt->setDescricao(NULL);
            }
            if (isset($row->Categoria)){
                 $objt->setCategoria($row->categoria);
            }  
            else{
                $objt->setcategoria(NULL);     
            }
            if (isset( $row->autor)){
                $objt->setAutor($row->autor);
            }
            else{
                $objt->setautor(NULL);    
            }  
            if(isset( $row->data)){
                $objt->setData($row->data);
            }
            else{
                $objt->setdata(NULL);    
            }          
            if(isset( $row->Data_update )){
                $objt->setData($row->data);
            }
            else{
                $objt->setdata_update(NULL);    
            }      
            $results[] = $objt;

        }
    }
    return $results;   
}
```

public function inserirperguntas ($id_questionario ,$texto_pergunta){
     try{

```
    $stmt = "
      INSERT INTO
        perguntas (myid, id_questionario, texto_pergunta)
      VALUES (null, :id_questionario, :texto_pergunta)";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($stmt);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id_questionario", $id_questionario);
    $stmt->bindValue(":texto_pergunta", $texto_pergunta);

    $stmt->execute();
  return $this->processResults($stmt); 
  }
  catch (Exception $e){  
    $log = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($log, "ERRO EM 'pesRastreioDAO -> instPesRast' -=- DIA ".date("d/m/Y")." -=- HORA ".date("H:m:s")."\r\n".$e->getMessage()."\r\n");
    fclose($log);
    return false;
  }
}

public function insertRespostas ($id_perguntas, $texto_resposta, $correct){
    try{
        $stmt = "
            INSERT INTO
            respostas (myid, id_perguntas, texto_resposta, correct)
            VALUES (null, :id_perguntas, :texto_resposta, :correct)";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($stmt);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_perguntas", $id_perguntas);
        $stmt->bindValue(":texto_resposta", $texto_resposta);

        $stmt->bindValue(":correct", $correct);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $this->processResults($stmt); 
    }
    catch (Exception $e){  
        $log = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($log, "ERRO EM 'pesRastreioDAO -> instPesRast' -=- DIA ".date("d/m/Y")." -=- HORA ".date("H:m:s")."\r\n".$e->getMessage()."\r\n");
        fclose($log);
        return false;
    }
}
```

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `perguntas` (
>     `myid` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `id_questionario` int(8) NOT NULL,
>     `texto_pergunta` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`myid`),
>     KEY `fk_questionario_pergunta` (`id_questionario`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questionario` (
>     `myid` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `nome_questionario` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `descricao` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `categoria` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `data` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>     `data_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>     `autor` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`myid`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=92 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `respostas` (
>     `myid` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `texto_resposta` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `id_perguntas` int(150) NOT NULL,
>     `correct` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`myid`),
>     KEY `fk_respostas_perguntas` (`id_perguntas`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>   ALTER TABLE `perguntas`
>     ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_questionario_pergunta` FOREIGN KEY (`id_questionario`) REFERENCES `questionario` (`myid`);

--

### -- Limitadores para a tabela `respostas`

ALTER TABLE `respostas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_respostas_perguntas` FOREIGN KEY (`id_perguntas`) REFERENCES `perguntas` (`myid`);
COMMIT;

Comment: voce vai ter que usar um conceito chamado RollBack e begintransaction do sql e que tem no php tb

Comment: Tudo isso vai virar uma função só, onde no começo tu vai colocar begintransation();  ai no catch coloca o Rollback();

Comment: Outra coisa que vai ter que usar é o getLastInsertID();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando PDO do Mysql

```
con = new PDO( ... dados da conexão ...);
```

você inicia a transação com

```
con->beginTransaction();
```

após cada execute do sql (como desejar), você recupera o ID do elemento inserido por último com

```
$id = con->lastInsertId();
```

dai você pode reutilizar esse $id no próximo sql.

Quando ocorrer algum problema na hora de dar o execute (no caso ele retornar falso), você usa o rollBack para desfazer tudo que ja foi feito (e não se esqueça de usar try catch para recuperar exceções PDOException)

```
con->rollBack();
```

Caso dê tudo certo você finaliza a transação com commit

```
con->commit();
```

Fontes com exemplos de códigos:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.begintransaction.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.commit.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.rollback.php